# Capture Searchview clear button event

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to capture the clear button event in the search view for an android project:

```
SearchView _search = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.publicSearchview);
_search.QueryTextSubmit += SearchBtn_Click;
ImageView _closeBtn = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.search_close_btn);
_closeBtn.Click += CloseBtn_Click;
```

But the _closeBtn is always null. Any suggestions??

```
    <SearchView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/publicSearchview" />
```

Comment: updated the answer please check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `SearchView` is not being set to icon'fy, this will work:

```
var _search = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView1);
int searchCloseButtonId = _search.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
var _closeBtn = FindViewById<ImageView>(searchCloseButtonId);
_closeBtn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{ 
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Close Click", ToastLength.Long).Show();
};
```